# I want to show facebook page status and comments on my website

Tags: php, facebook

All.
I want to show the facebook page status and comments and also the current updates on my website's facebook area in footer.
I have searched alot but found this link always http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ link.
but this link is about the comments posted on the website.
I want the statuses and updates from a specific facebook page feeds.
please help me out...

regards:
Abdul Sattar

Comment: start by reading this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall/

Neosmart a Facebook Wall Jquery Plugin Will Help You...

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $result; }

 require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php'; //you have to download facebook SDK
$page_id ='387244981394957';
 $access_token ='478845318813590|BjcO5R6IteJHg1m2xsVlanTegZY'; 
//Please get your own access tolken
     getSslPage('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id .
     '/posts?access_token=' . $access_token);

//Interpret data
 $fbdata = json_decode($json_object, true);
var_dump($fbdata);
```